# Ollydbg target runs automatically

Tags: debuggers, pe, ollydbg

I have a target that automatically runs after I load it in to Ollydbg. This form, doesn't stop at the entry point (but continues to execute and at a point it pauses, I have to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd>.)

Is there any way to debug it ?

Answer (score 5):

set the radio button `system breakpoint` in debugging options

```
alt+o -> events -> make first pause at -> system breakpoint
```

then analyze if TLS Callbacks , DllInit Routines exist in the executable
these routines can alter the execution behavior

Comment: FYI, [OllyDbg 2](http://ollydbg.de/version2.html) supports automatic breakpoints on TLS callbacks. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/malware-lu/wiki/en_malware_Ysreef#Unpack) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found this type of automatic run when a .NET target is loaded in Olly. If you are trying to debug a .NET target, consider Reflector instead of Olly.